# Searchable data in CosmosDb with Graph api

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, azure-cognitive-search

My team uses CosmosDb to store data.
For our use case some of this data needs to be searchable.
Currently there are some filters in the Gremlin that has been implemented in CosmosDb so far, but not enough to suit our needs, which are mainly search in text.
This would be implemented to make a fuzzy search for a vertex, say, a person, where both name, email and company name would be included in the text.

In https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/413 there was some talk of some string filters, but there has been no updates for a while.
My question is would it be better to use Azure Search for this use case?

We could add a step in the pipeline that would synchronize our data to an Azure Search service upon doing CRUD, but this would mean slower CRUD as well as data duplication, and the consumer of our api would have to use a search endpoint to get an id, and then do an additional lookup afterwards to get any related data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can expose the data you want to make searchable to Azure Search using a "vanilla" (non-Gremlin) SQL API query, consider using [Azure Search indexers for Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb). However, for simple string matching searches Azure Search may be an overkill - use it if you need more sophisticated searches (natural language-aware in many languages, custom tokenization, custom scoring, etc.).

If you need a tighter integration between Cosmos DB Graph API and Azure Search, vote for [this UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/13285011-add-graph-databases-to-your-data-sources-eg-neo4).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, went straight in and voted on the suggestion because it would be really neat.

As for using Azure Search for simple string matching searches, I think you're right in it being overkill.
The other reason I'm hesitant about using Azure Search is the addition of an extra step for the client. We are currently creating a GraphQL layer on top of the CosmosDb, so I would really like for client applications to be able to use that without too much extra overhead.

Comment: I opened an issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/473
If their planned string filters include regex, that should be more than enough to cover my use case.